# Ember.Router loses context for dynamic segments on page reload

Tags: ember.js

I've been trying to debug this for a while now, and I may have figured out what the problem is, let me explain what is happening by use of a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanvanderbyl/mfqEB//)

Navigate to http://fiddle.jshell.net/ivanvanderbyl/mfqEB/show/#/projects/1, you'll notice the dynamic segment in the url is replaced with `null` — it should stay as `1`

From what I can gather, after routing once, Ember Router then makes a call to update the URL, replacing the dynamic segments with the values it gets from the respective instantiated objects, in this case App.Project.

The problem is that `App.Project` is not loaded at this point so `id` is `null`

Now whether this is a bug or an implementation failure on my part, has anyone else seen this?

Comment: This was a bug, but it was fixed [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/1dafa668ba13e4b2d44fe91faf314a1e959a8ac2). Weird

Comment: Yeah it seems to have been broken by something within Ember routing recently, I managed to replicate the issue without ember-data. It seems the router is literally routing twice, dropping context on the second run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much investigation the correct solution to this is to simply not specify the primary key attribute on the model, in this case I should not have been specifying the ID attribute on the Project model. Ember Data handles this internally.

Thanks to Peter Wagenet for pointing this out on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Moving connectOutlets from projects.index directly into projects seems to do the trick. Don't ask me why though.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZXYy/)

```
Router: Ember.Router.extend(
  location: 'hash'
  enableLogging: true

  root: Ember.Route.extend(

    listProjects: Ember.Route.transitionTo("projects.index")
    showProject:  Ember.Route.transitionTo("projects.show")

    index: Ember.Route.extend(
      route: "/"
      redirectsTo: 'projects.index'
    )

    projects: Ember.Route.extend(
      route: '/projects'

      connectOutlets: ((router) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('projects', App.Project.find())
      )

      index: Ember.Route.extend(
        route: '/'
      )

      add: Ember.Route.extend(
        route: '/new'
      )

      show: Ember.Route.extend(
        route: '/:project_id'

        connectOutlets: (router, project) ->
          console.log project.get('name')

          # router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('project', project)
      )
    )

  )
)
```

Comment: There was an issue about this (I can't find it, don't remember the id) that basically forces use `connectOutlets` in both the parent route and the leaf route even when you only have an index view for that route.

Comment: In practice this doesn't seem to work, it also introduces an unwanted extra request at that point. I've lodged an issue in Github about this https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1151